# How to show the subsection within the header on every page starting with a specific page?

Tags: fancyhdr, pagestyle

I want to write the name of my subsection on every page header. However, I only want the header to contain the name of the subsection once the regular text starts, i.e. after the table of contents, list of figures etc...

Could someone help me with that? So far, I only managed to come up with this code which prints only the section name on every page, but not the subsection.

Any held would be much appreciated!!

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Objectives of the thesis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do get the subsection name in each header of the main part if I add some reasonable document structure around the code fragment to make it compile. Please post a complete compilable document that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please see the code in my answer below. It should be able to compile now but in my header it only shows the section title, not the subsection title for me.